# how to pass values to request object from php file

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I am having a small problem. I have developed a c# file which accepts data in Request object. the Request object contains a string and then i performs various operations on that string but the problem is that I need to call this aspx file from a PHP file.

This is how i am accepting data in the ASPX file

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try{
            byte[] byteArray;

            byteArray = Request.BinaryRead(Request.TotalBytes);

               // This bytes array to string method perfectly converts the request data into string.
            string xmlString = Utility.Utility.ByteArrayToString(byteArray);
```

now if i am passing a JSON string from PHP file then please guide me how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

If it is a JSON string then you could use a JSON serializer in order to parse deserialize this string into a class. For example you could use the built-in [`JavaScriptserializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class or [`Json.NET`](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx).

Let's suppose that the PHP file sent the following JSON to the body of a POST request:

```
{"foo":"bar","baz":123}
```

Now you could define a corresponding model that will match this JSON structure:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public int Baz { get; set; }
}
```

and then read the JSON payload from the request and use the serializer to deserialize it back to your model:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
    {
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        MyModel model = serializer.Deserialize<MyModel>(json);
        // you could use the model here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but the thing is that the data on this page will be posted by a PHP file.

Comment: That doesn't really matter as far as the data is in an interoperable format such as JSON. ASP.NET doesn't really care who posted the data. Whether it was a PHP script, a Java servlet or a Chineese hacker attempting to steal the passwords from your database. ASP.NET talks the HTTP protocol language.

Comment: :( I got your point but let me explain what i want to do. I have a simple PHP page and the code is `<form action = "http://localhost:58358/services/testService.aspx" method = "post">
 <textarea id = "test" name = "test">{"shipCode": [
"test1",
"test2" ]
}
</textarea> 
<input type= "submit">
</form>` and i just want to read that jsonstring in the xmlString  variable. I would be really glad if you will be able to help me out. I dont want to serialize that json string

Comment: Great, looking forward to your explanation.